# WPF MediaElement on Remote Desktop

Tags: wpf, rdp

I have a simple WPF application that all it has is a media element:

```
<MediaElement Name="TheMedia" Stretch="Fill" LoadedBehavior="Play"/>
```

I initialize the source in the code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string file = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", Environment.CurrentDirectory, "movie.mp4");
    Uri uri = new Uri(file);
    TheMedia.Source = uri;
}
```

When I run it on my computer it works
when I run it on a remote desktop it does one of the 2 things dependent on the RD Sesion Host Configuration -> RDP-Tcp -> Properties -> Client Settings -> Audio and video playback:
if it is checked, I see the video with no sound
if it is not checked, I hear the video but no display

Any ideas?

Comment: This is probably more of a system issue rather than your WPF program. Can you view the mp4 using RDC?

Comment: Yes, I cam both see and hear the mp4 on the remote desktop regardless of the properties